# How to send a CLI List<double>^ to native C++ via TCP sockets?

Tags: c++, list, stream, c++-cli

I have a CLI layer communicating to a native C++ layer via TCP. I am stuck trying to send an arbitrary length CLI List to this layer.

Comment: You are taking a list of doubles and serializing them (storing them in a "flat binary" format) and deserializing them at the other end.  There are literally thousands or more ways people do this.  What have you tried?  What are your constraints?  How big is the list?   What are your performance vs debugability requirements?  Do bandwidth costs matter?  Can the recieving application process partial lists or does it need the entire thing to start working?  Are they both using the same IEEE floating point hardware?  Are they on the same computer, or do you need to use network byte order?

Comment: I tried to use NetworkStream, but I am unable to find the syntax for it for CLI. The server client are on the same PC. The list will contain under 1000 entries. The entire list has to be sent, along with 3 other equally sized ones, for it to work.

Comment: Wait, do you mean "Command line interface" or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx ?  You tagged your question [tag:command-line-interface] not [tag:c++-cli]

Comment: Can you send one `double`? If so, have you tried sending one `double` `Count` times?

Comment: Stack overflow expanded it automatically. I meant to say Common Language Runtime (CLR)/C++ .NET

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using .Net classes for your network communication. Since you're asking about how to write doubles, as opposed to how to make a TCP connection in the first place, I'm assuming that you already have a [`NetworkStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx) instance that you want to write the doubles to.

To write a double to the network stream, instantiate a [`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx), iterate over your `List<double>^`, and call the [`Write(double)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez8wcba9.aspx) method for each double.

```
List<double>^ list = ...
NetworkStream^ ns = ...
BinaryWriter^ bw = gcnew BinaryWriter(ns);

for each (double d in list)
{
    bw.Write(d);
}
```